# Unit test the DAO layer at all?

Tags: testing, junit, dao

How do you experienced developers comment these lines by Michael Feathers:

**A test is not a unit test if:**

- *It talks to the database*
- *It communicates across the network*
- *It touches the file system*
- *It can't run at the same time as any of your other unit tests*
- *You have to do special things to your environment (such as editing
  config. files) to run it.*

Now I was wondering if I should unit test my DAO classes...
Will I get more advantages or disadvantages by unit testing the DAO layer? Share your thoughts please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feathers isn't saying don't write such tests.  He's saying they're not **unit tests**, because he defines a unit test as "[small, they test a method or the interaction of a couple of methods. ... a "binary chop" that allows you to discover whether the problem is in your logic or in the things are you interfacing with.](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923)"  And he's right - the Agile/XP/Scrum intention of unit testing is to provide a **fast** red light/green light determination if a small piece of code is functioning correctly.

Comment: Ok I see, then I guess we should call these integration tests.